# It is possible to change the date language on Altair or Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, altair

I have no idea if this task can be made from Altair or Pandas, but I'm looking for the documentation to change the `date` language of my graph.

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mariorz/covid19-mx-time-series/master/data/covid19_confirmed_mx.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0)
#df = pd.read_csv(url)

df = df.loc['Colima','18-03-2020':'18-11-2020']
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d-%m-%Y')

%run urban_theme.py

alt.Chart(df.reset_index()).mark_line().encode(
    alt.X('index:T', title = " "),
    alt.Y('Colima:Q', title = " "),
).properties(
    title = "Casos acumulados",
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: You can try the `locale` package and run `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'es_ES.utf8')` right after the `imports`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not well documented currently, but there is some relevant information in  [How to set locale in Altair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58014796/how-to-set-locale-in-altair).

You can set a Spanish time format locale for your chart like this:

```python
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from urllib import request
import json

# fetch & enable a Spanish timeFormat locale.
with request.urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/d3/d3-time-format/master/locale/es-ES.json') as f:
  es_time_format = json.load(f)
alt.renderers.set_embed_options(timeFormatLocale=es_time_format)

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mariorz/covid19-mx-time-series/master/data/covid19_confirmed_mx.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url, index_col=0)
#df = pd.read_csv(url)

df = df.loc['Colima','18-03-2020':'18-11-2020']
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d-%m-%Y')

alt.Chart(df.reset_index()).mark_line().encode(
    alt.X('index:T', title = " "),
    alt.Y('Colima:Q', title = " "),
).properties(
    title = "Casos acumulados",
    width = 800
)
```

[image]